# Selecting more than one option

Tags: jquery

I have the following code working pretty well, but I want to be able to select more than one option if need be: http://jsfiddle.net/exlondoner/MKa3n/

Can anyone help?

JS:

```
$('.media-select-option').on('click', function() {
    $('.media-select-option').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');     
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.media-select-option').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.m-overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MKa3n/1/)

Comment: Thanks Palash, I had it working that way, but was wondering if there way a way without adding an additional class.

Comment: I think class would be a better option to use here.

Comment: Right, I agree.
Another issue I just noticed, if I uncheck everything how do I get my check box to return to an 'X'?

Comment: Let me see that. In the meantime, you can also post that as a question, so that other users also can give some helpful ideas on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because there is no such element with class `m-overlay-close-btn`

```
$('.overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKa3n/2/)